# What kind of advertisement am I allowed to show and still comply with GDPR?

Tags: gdpr, advertising

I am running a website which servers advertisements to stay profitable (one banner). Now I found out, that none of the advertisement delivery networks that I use, explain how they process the visitor's data.

Now with GDPR, can I still include these ads, without knowing how they process user data or is that a violation? Is it the advertisement network who must ensure compliance or the webmaster who delivers the ads?

Comment: I assume that this webmaster is in Europe and the site targets European visitors?    If those are not the case, the GDPR is probably irrelevant.

Comment: the website is hosted in the EU, I am a EU citizen residing outside of the EU and my website is targeted towards any kind of people all over the world, including Europeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a couple of things you should be considering.

**Setting Cookies**

If you are setting a cookie on your website and passing this on to a 3rd party, this counts as personal identifiable information (PII). If you want to set this cookie, you need a user to opt-in, then set the cookie.

If you want a simple way to do this, have a look at [this google tag manager approach.][1]

While you may be using different services, below is what Google & Facebook are providing. That might help give you some direction for the Ad Networks you work with.

- **Google (AdSense)- Pausing ad-requests until cookie consent have been given** https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/adsense-gdpr-consent
- **Google - Tools to help publishers comply with the GDPR** https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7666366
- **Google - Code Examples** https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9042142?hl=en&ref_topic=7670012
- **Facebook - Cookie Consent Guide for Sites and Apps**  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/privacy/

  [1]:
  https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/cookies-with-google-tag-manager/